# Initialize base class member in derived constructor if base is inherited via template

Tags: c++, templates, mixins, derived-class

Given I know that a certain member `a` exists in my base class, how can I refer to it using my template-derived class? Even if I fully qualify `a`, it doesn't work:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cKfdPcojo)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct base {
    int a;
};

template <typename ImplType>
struct derived : public ImplType {

    derived()
        : a{2}
    {}

    auto print() {
        std::cout << ImplType::a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived<base> d{};
    d.print();
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:14:11: error: class 'derived<ImplType>' does not have any field named 'a'
   14 |         : a{2}
      |           ^
```

Comment: Even without template `a{2}` would be wrong, either use base class constructor, or assign it in body constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Use the aggregate base class initialization

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    int a;
};

template <typename ImplType>
struct derived : public ImplType {
    derived()
        : ImplType{2}
    {}

    auto print() {
        std::cout << ImplType::a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived<base> d{};
    d.print();
}
```

Comment: Ok what if base is not an aggregate?

Comment: If it's not an aggregate, it has a constructor, right? Then use its constructor in the initializing list.

Comment: I hoped to avoid that because say I have possible 10 possible base classes, it gets really messy really quickly :/

Comment: It smells XY-problem. If a derived class restricts, hardcodes and accesses the content of base classes, then it's a bad design. What the actual task are you solving?

Comment: If you really don't want to call a base class constructor explicitly, you can assign ImplType::a in the body of the constructor.  I agree with @273K, however, that if there's a reason you cannot call the base class constructor, it's probably an issue with the design.

Comment: I'm creating a class that works with either a custom StringType or string_view. If string_view is supplied, the user needs to provide an allocator template argument and the interface will accept that, whereas with custom StringType it will derive the allocator type from the supplied string type and use it to construct all internal data structure. My thought was I could just mixin the base class to be used which would either be the one that assigns allocators or the other one that doesn't. But it's getting out of hand